# Traversing Through Multiple Associations (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, paperclip

I am a little stuck on this one. I would appreciate input.

**Overview**

I am trying to get the output I require in this friendship model i.e. the files the current user's friends have uploaded.

**Models**

Like all other friendship models, `User` is self-referencing as `:friend`.

```
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
end
```

This is my Paperclip model:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :document
end
```

This one is generated through Devise:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :login

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "120x120!" }

    has_many :uploads
    has_many :shares
    has_many :friends, :through => :shares
    has_many :inverse_shares, :class_name => "Share", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
    has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_shares, :source => :user
end
```

**Attempts**

The furthest I have gotten into would be the level in which I am able to output the user's friends' `:username(s)`, where `@check = current_user` in the controller:

```
<% @check.shares.each |j| %>
        <%= j.friend.username %>
<% end %>
```

**Question**

How do I output the `:file_name`, `:file_type`, and `:document` of each of the current user's friends? I intend to have my page look like this:

User's Friend 1 Files

- File Name
- File Type
- Document

User's Friend 2 Files

- File Name
- File Type
- Document

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) :

> Paperclip will wrap up to four attributes (all prefixed with that
>   attachment's name, so you can have multiple attachments per model if
>   you wish) and give them a friendly front end. These attributes are:
>
> ```
> <attachment>_file_name
> <attachment>_file_size
> <attachment>_content_type
> <attachment>_updated_at
> ```

Given that, and with your attachment name of "document" :

```
<% current_user.shares.each do |share|%>
    <%= share.friend.username %>
    <% share.friend.uploads.each do |upload| %>
        <%= upload.document_file_name %>
        <%= upload.document_content_type %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the response. Unfortunately, I get an `undefined method 'document'` error.

Comment: Sorry, my previous answer was pre-coffee, and you need to get through the uploads association. Try the edited version.

Comment: I was able to use my predefined methods as well--thank you very much!